# How to write the addDough Method to my Pizza using the decorator DP

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, decorator

I'm creating three types of Pizza(Chicken, Pepperoni and Vegetarian) and each of them can have extra toppings which will increase the pizza price(like extra cheese, sausage...) so I know I need to use the decorator DP but my problem is that I have 2 types of dough(Flatbread & Thin Crust) and each of my pizza SHOULD have a dough but I don't know where to add that dough part.
Here's my Pizza interface:

```
public interface Pizza {
    public String getDescription();
    public double getCost();    
 }
```

Here's my Chicken Pizza Class(pepperoni and veg will be added later):

```
public class ChickenPizza implements Pizza {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {

        return "Chicken";
    }
    @Override
    public double getCost() {

        return 10;
    }
}
```

My ToppingDecorator class:

```
public abstract class ToppingDecorator implements Pizza {
    protected Pizza tempPizza;
    public ToppingDecorator(Pizza newPizza) {
        tempPizza=newPizza;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return tempPizza.getDescription();
    }

    @Override
    public double getCost() {
        return tempPizza.getCost();
    }
}
```

And my ExtraCheese Class(sausage and other toppings will be added later):

```
public class ExtraCheese extends ToppingDecorator{

    public ExtraCheese(Pizza newPizza) {
        super(newPizza);
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return tempPizza.getDescription()+", Extra Cheese";
    }


    public double getCost() {
        return tempPizza.getCost()+2;
    }
}
```

So my question is: At first I thought that I should make 2 classes 1 for the Flatbread Dough and the other for the Thin Crust Dough(like I did to the Extra Cheese) but it won't change the cost, then I thought that I should make an abstract get and set methods in the Pizza interface but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure you do this the right way. Because in my opinion it's more logical to have the dough and topping as properties of the pizza.
But following your way you would have to have the 2 classes and just return `tempPizza.getCost()`.

Comment: @Sascha but not all the Pizza that will be created will have toppings so I can't have them as properties, but all pizza will have dough and dough won't change their price.

Comment: You can have empty properties (e.g an empty `List<Topping> toppings`). Eventually the question is: Do you want to use the decorator pattern exclusively or not?

Comment: @Sascha no I have no constraint about what DP to use and I don't even have to use a DP, I thought of using the decorator DP because after I finish the code I'm going to create a GUI which the user than choses what type of pizza and dough he wants and if he wants to add the toppings and when he press the finish button his choices will be sent to a Pizza table(PizzaName,DoughType,ExtraToppings(which can be NULL),Price) using the gdbc, so i'm thinking I'll create the Dough just like the extra toppings and in the GUI the user will have to chose one type.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how we can implement decorate pattern to decorate objects with extra ingredients. Let's take a look first on description what is [decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator):

- Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically.
  Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for
  extending functionality.
- Client-specified embellishment of a core object by recursively
  wrapping it.
- Wrapping a gift, putting it in a box, and wrapping the box.

As you can see above restrictions are wide and we have some flexibility. We could think about pizza like about list of ingredients. We can choose dough, vegetables, etc. We can treat pizza kind as ingredient also. Of course we can create two model hierarchies: one for all pizzas and one for all other ingredients but one hierarchy should be enough. Also, for predefined ingredients we can create new class or just create flexible constructor which allow us to create as many ingredients dynamically as we need. You can easily bind decorator pattern with [builder](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) or/and [abstract factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory).

Below example shows simple decorators with builder pattern used for building pizzas with predefined ingredients and extra wishes:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class DesignPatterns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ingredient chicken = new PizzaBuilder().chicken()
                .withFlatBread()
                .withSausage()
                .build();
        System.out.println(chicken);

        Ingredient pepperoni = new PizzaBuilder().pepperoni()
                .withThinCrust()
                .withSausage()
                .withExtraCheese()
                .build();
        System.out.println(pepperoni);

        Ingredient vegetarian = new PizzaBuilder().vegetarian()
                .withCustomerWish("Mushrooms", BigDecimal.ONE)
                .build();
        System.out.println(vegetarian);
    }
}

class FlatBread extends Ingredient {

    public FlatBread(Ingredient pizza) {
        super(pizza, "Flat bread", new BigDecimal("0.25"));
    }
}

class ThinCrust extends Ingredient {
    public ThinCrust(Ingredient pizza) {
        super(pizza, "Thin Crust", new BigDecimal("0.50"));
    }
}

class ChickenPizza extends Ingredient {

    public ChickenPizza() {
        super("Chicken", new BigDecimal("3.25"));
    }
}

class Pepperoni extends Ingredient {

    public Pepperoni() {
        super("Pepperoni", new BigDecimal("4.50"));
    }
}

class Ingredient {

    private final Ingredient base;
    private final String name;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    public Ingredient(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this(null, name, price);
    }

    public Ingredient(Ingredient base, String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.base = base;
    }

    public String getName() {
        if (base != null) {
            return base.getName() + ", " + name;
        }

        return name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        if (base != null) {
            return price.add(base.getPrice());
        }

        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return '\'' + getName() + "' costs = " + getPrice() + " $";
    }
}

class PizzaBuilder {

    IngredientsBuilder chicken() {
        return new IngredientsBuilder(new ChickenPizza());
    }

    IngredientsBuilder pepperoni() {
        return new IngredientsBuilder(new Pepperoni());
    }

    IngredientsBuilder vegetarian() {
        return new IngredientsBuilder(new Ingredient("Vegetarian", new BigDecimal("2.89")));
    }

    // other pizza types

    class IngredientsBuilder {

        private Ingredient instance;

        private IngredientsBuilder(Ingredient pizza) {
            this.instance = pizza;
        }

        IngredientsBuilder withFlatBread() {
            instance = new FlatBread(instance);
            return this;
        }

        IngredientsBuilder withThinCrust() {
            instance = new ThinCrust(instance);
            return this;
        }

        IngredientsBuilder withSausage() {
            instance = new Ingredient(instance, "Sausage", new BigDecimal("0.49"));
            return this;
        }

        IngredientsBuilder withExtraCheese() {
            instance = new Ingredient(instance, "Extra cheese", new BigDecimal("0.56"));
            return this;
        }

        IngredientsBuilder withCustomerWish(String name, BigDecimal price) {
            instance = new Ingredient(instance, name, price);
            return this;
        }

        // other ingredients

        Ingredient build() {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
'Chicken, Flat bread, Sausage' costs = 3.99 $
'Pepperoni, Thin Crust, Sausage, Extra cheese' costs = 6.05 $
'Vegetarian, Mushrooms' costs = 3.89 $
```